# CNN-BERT Text Classification good results on train and val, but bad prediction on testing

Tags: neural-network, keras, cnn, bert, text-classification

I built a Keras model to predict hoax news and true news using the CNN-BERT Text Classification algorithm with Categorical Classification, with label 1 indicating a hoax and 0 indicating true news.

Although the model I created appears to have good training and validation accuracy results, when I make predictions on the test set, it does not appear to be able to predict.

Pretrained BERT model that i used

```
tfhub_handle_encoder = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-512_A-8/1')

tfhub_handle_preprocess = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3')
```

Model

```
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers


def build_CNN_classifier_model():
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
    preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
    encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
    encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
    outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    net = outputs['pooled_output'] # [batch_size, 768].
    net = sequence_output = outputs["sequence_output"] #[batch_size, seq_length, 768]
      
    
    net = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, (2), activation='relu')(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2)(net)
#     net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
    
    net = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, (2), activation='relu')(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2)(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(net)
    
    net = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, (2), activation='relu')(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2)(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(net)
    
#     net = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(net)
    
    net = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(net)
    
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(net)
                                #,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
                                #bias_regularizer=regularizers.L2(1e-4),
                                #activity_regularizer=regularizers.L2(1e-5))
                                
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
    
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(net)
                                #,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
                                #bias_regularizer=regularizers.L2(1e-4),
                                #activity_regularizer=regularizers.L2(1e-5))
                                
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
    
#     net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name='classifier')(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax", name='classifier')(net)
    
    return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)
```

compile

```
from official.nlp import optimization  # to create AdamW optmizer

epochs = 10
steps_per_epoch = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy()
num_train_steps = steps_per_epoch * epochs
num_warmup_steps = int(0.1*num_train_steps)

init_lr = 1e-5
optimizer = optimization.create_optimizer(init_lr=init_lr,
                                          num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
                                          num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
                                          optimizer_type='adamw')

cnn_classifier_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                             loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                             metrics=tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy'))



print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
cnn_history = cnn_classifier_model.fit(x=train_ds,
                                       validation_data=val_ds,
                                       epochs=epochs,
                                       class_weight=class_weight
                                      )
```

Results

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Test Prediction

[image]

it seems like my test model can't tell which one is hoax news and which one is real news, what's the problem?

Comment: You only tried 2 test samples?

Comment: I tried with different samples by replacing the text in the real and hoax datasets when predicting the dataset, the sample above is an example.

Comment: Try it with a thousand (or a million, I don't know how big your dataset is) samples and check your stats. If your training accuracy is 90%, the test should not be much lower (but is expected to be lower). But I don't think you can safely extract any conclusions for checking some samples manually. Maybe those specific examples where too hard. If *everything* is classified wrongly, then something is indeed wrong, but the information provided here does not suffice.